# Setting ViewPager's current item from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using a `ViewPager` in my app, with the initial fragment being a `ListView` and the other fragments being details of the `ListView`.  The user can either manually select an item in the `ListView` or swipe though the various details.  I have the swipe working, but I'm not sure how to get the item selection working.  I'm assuming I need to do something in `onListItemClick` of the `ListView` and I know I can use `setCurrentItem` of the `ViewPager`, but the `ViewPager` is in the `Activity` and the `ListView` is in the fragment so I'm not sure how to get both working.

This might be something obvious, but I'm new to using a `ViewPager` and there's doesn't seem to be alot of documentation out there, mostly tutorials on getting a basic `ViewPager` working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three ways of setting up fragment/activity communication:

1. You can define an interface aka a Listener that the activity implements.

    Reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html Check out the section called "Creating event callbacks to the activity"
2. Use an EventBus library  such as [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto) or  [EventBus](http://greenrobot.github.com/EventBus/) to create a publisher/subscriber system where your activity is the subscriber and your fragments publish events.
3. You can use the [LocalBroadcastManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to send out a message through intents that the activity intercepts by creating a BroadcastReceiver with an action string specified by you. Heres an example of a typical use case: [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager)

Comment: #1 worked for me and was pretty easy to implement.  Can't believe I missed that section in the documentation.  Thanks!